How do you calculate total code coverage for Android code using Jacoco?
How can I calculate the total unit test coverage using JaCoCo for my entire code base, not just the classes with unit tests written?
I tried using JaCoCo, but it's only showing unit test coverage for the classes that have unit tests written

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
